# show one Recyclerview item at a time - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My `Recyclerview` item occupies the whole screen height and width. 
I wish to implement a `custom scroll` inside the `Recyclerview` such that it scrolls only one item at a time ( similar to `News In Shorts` app ).

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Duplicate question.
Please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41988804/7182978).

Answer (score 4):

**You need to add just two below Lines**

```
RecylerView mRecylerView = (RecylerView).findViewById(R.id.mRecylerView)
SnapHelper mSnapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
mSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecylerView);
```

SnapHelper can be used to snap the child to any imaginary point or any pixel on the screen

Comment: Great answer! :-) But could you elaborate why it works?

Comment: SnapHelper can be used to snap the child to any imaginary point or any pixel on the screen

Comment: And if you could edit that to your answer so users don't have to work through comments. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
parentScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        findViewById(R.id.childScrollView).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return false;
    }
});
childScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of
        // child view
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Viswajit - Thanks for the response, but could you be more specific about how to implement this code and where.

Comment: In my code am using LinearLayoutManager as am implementing linear scrolling of the list item. So do i have to override certain functions inside the LayoutManager.?