# RecyclerView with only one item displayed on screen

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView` with items `ImageView`. I want to make `RecyclerView` to display only one item at time, dragging to edge like `ViewPager`, when changing. Anyone knows how to achieve this?

I'm using code from this source:

[Android Simple RecyclerView Widget Example](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-recyclerview-widget-example/)

Only one difference is that I don't have `TextView`, only `ImageView`.

Comment: If you can add your code you have right now, this will help to do good answer that fit your question

Comment: Well you can set your item view size to be equal to the screen size

Comment: But the problem is that only one item must be displayed at time, one picture. And when I swipe, it must change next :/

Comment: Okay. so you need a vertical swiping exactly like a ViewPager?

Comment: That's right, hegazy :) I tried use ViewPager with axis transformation, but the performance is not good.

Comment: I'm using an already made VerticalViewPager that supports vertical swiping and the performance is realy good. I'm gonna write it in an answer.

Comment: Did you try putting VerticalViewPager in standard ViewPager to achive both Horizonal and Vertial swiping?

Comment: Oh. you meen like a grid? like a horizontal view pager in which every page is a vertical viewpager or reversed?

Comment: Yes. I have _n_ elements in horizontal axis, each of _n_ got _x_ different photos - vertical axis (each _x_ is not constant for all _n_, some got 2, some 4). Yesterday I put VerticalViewPager in standard ViewPager, receiving 3 fragments and performance was bad, even on Note 3 :/

Comment: You won't believe me that this where I used the library that I mentioned!

Comment: So should I use lib which you mentioned - castorflex/VerticalViewPager - and put this in standard ViewPager?

Comment: that's what I'm doing and it works good for me. I don't in your case. what's is the problem with the performance. may be the images are large. may be your aren't using the ViewHolder pattern....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from I see you need a vertical ViewPager. I'm using [castorflex/VerticalViewPager](https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager)
  library for achieving that for one of my projects. It works just like a ViewPager, no code changes as I can see It's just a copy paste from the v19 ViewPager available in the support lib, where he changed all the left/right into top/bottom and X into Y.

Comment: VerticalViewPager inside HorizontalViewPager works perfectly. Instead of FragmentPagerAdapter, I used now PagerAdapter in VerticalViewPager. Maximum 5% CPU usage on Note 3. Thank you for help :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I use it with FragmentStatePagerAdapter and it also works great ;)

Comment: Currently (2020) there is already Google's official implementation of the same thing, they call it ViewPager2 and compared to ViewPager the ViewPager2 is capable of vertical scrolling (https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#vertical-support)

Answer (score 47):

You can use the PagerSnapHelper class:

```
RecyclerView recyclerFoodItemsHorizontal = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_food_items_horizontal);
SnapHelper mSnapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
mSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerFoodItemsHorizontal);
```

It will work similarly to ViewPager.

Comment: @KshitijJain, I'm getting an error "Cannot resolve symbol PagerSnapHelper". Please help :(

Comment: @Rakesh Please include recycler view library in gradle.

Comment: @KshitijJain, yeah I got it. I had to update the recycler view version to 25.2.0. Earlier I was using 25.0.0. I hope it wouldn't affect any other stuffs.

Comment: Great!  I thought to rewrite to page adapter!

Comment: Really great solution!

Comment: save my day, thanks a lot