# RecyclerView Scroll one element at a time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

I have a Recyclerview containing images, each image filling the view completely. I want the user to be able to scroll them one at a time, so it does not scroll more than one element, and it stops at the beginning of each element.

I tried adding a scroll listener, but I am unable to lock the scrolling.

Do you know how to achieve this behavior?

Comment: why not have a simple Imageview and set GestureListener to it when you detect a scroll simply replace The ImagevIew with new Image

Comment: Duplicate question.
Please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41988804/7182978).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a RecyclerView. Use a ViewPager that has a vertical direction.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: Actually I used a [library](https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager) called RecyclerViewPager from lsjwzh, works really well.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43024818/recyclerview-horizontal-scroll-how-to-display-one-item-at-a-scroll-like-pager) the best solution I've could find is:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

Setting the orientation vertical it should work