# Recyclerview Horizontal scroll,How to display one item at a scroll like pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have to implement both vertical and horizontal scroll using recyclerView and pragmatically I can change the recyclerview orientation by using LinearLayoutManager to set the orientation.The problem is when Horizontal scroll its showing next item in the same page.I should only show one item at a time when we scroll should display next Item please help me to fix this or any suggetion.

```
**main.xml**

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/recyler_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/vertical_recycler_view"
    android:layout_below="@id/slelect_scroll"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

```
**row.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:background="#3e56ed"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<TextView
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtView"
    android:text="sample text"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtView2"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="sample text234"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Verical SCroll]

[image: Horizontal scroll]

Comment: What is the problem in using `ViewPager` then?

Comment: @Wizard no problem but I am handling this in Sigle List. So it would be great if it is RecyclerView. Since I have already implemented all the functionality in recyclerView with Vertical View.

Comment: This probably doesn't warrant a full answer, so just as a suggestion for you and anybody having similar problems: Another option would be to simply use ViewPager2, which is based on RecyclerView but also has the ViewPager capabilities.

Answer (score 94):

If you want RecyclerView to mimic the behavior of ViewPager --

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

Comment: How can I archive same for Vertical Scrolling Recycler View (Show only one row at a time)?

Comment: @kavie change LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL to LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL

Comment: How to do this but with only n numbers in the screen?