# Horizontal RecyclerView with nice animation Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to make such like horizontal recycle view with nice UI animation. 
Note: I can make horizontal recyclerview. but how can it start from middle and when scroll it comes in start? and secondly background image will be visible or invisible  animatedly according scrolling.

[image]

I want to make such like I already try ItemDecoration but when it load fast time start from left after if start from center any help.

[image]

Comment: can u tried for this ?

Comment: u can scroll to middle position of recyclerview on start of the activity `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(middle)` .. and do some animation at the background.. at onScroll of recyclerView

Comment: take a viewpager with Carousel layout. http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/06/carousel-layout-with-viewpager-in.html change the ratio of the pages as you need

Comment: H, did  you check Iflex apps inside home there is a view as like my view and i want exactly that . https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=iflix.play&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Set padding left on `Recyclerview` as below code to start your `recyclerView` row as per padding left :

[image]    [image]

your **Xml code** should be like this :

```
<LinearLayout
           android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
           android:background="@drawable/banner2"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="240dp">



           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
               android:paddingLeft="180dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
               android:id="@+id/recycler_kids"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:clipToPadding="false"
               app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


       </LinearLayout>
```

Look into this for detect hiding row on recyclerview to show background image [Hiding views in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574805/hiding-views-in-recyclerview)

Comment: Thanks For your replay. If i use paddingLeft  how to remove padding left when recycleview swipe left.
I want to make such like.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsATz.gif

Comment: I updated my code please check @t.gakk and reply, its workable code

Answer (score 1):

Linearlayout manager with horizontal orientation and `PagerSnapHelper()` will be helpful to achieve this. Following code from [pagersnap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43024818/recyclerview-horizontal-scroll-how-to-display-one-item-at-a-scroll-like-pager) will provide better illustration.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, 
LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

Answer (score 0):

To Start horizontal RecyclerView with a starting empty space Use:

**recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalSpaceItemDecoration(700));**

and define Class: **HorizontalSpaceItemDecoration();** as

```
public class HorizontalSpaceItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final int mHorizontalSpaceWidth;

    public HorizontalSpaceItemDecoration(int mHorizontalSpaceWidth) {
        this.mHorizontalSpaceWidth = mHorizontalSpaceWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
                               RecyclerView.State state) {
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
            outRect.left = mHorizontalSpaceWidth;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution is to add blank item at first.

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position==0){
            return 1;
        }else {
            return super.getItemViewType(position);
        }
    }
```

you need to create blank item in xml for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your adapter :

```
if (position == 0) {
    holder.card_zero.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.card_info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.card_pic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    holder.card_zero.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.card_info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.card_pic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```