# How to run two different animations on recyclerView consecutively?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal recyclerView, I want to animate it (by sliding right and then left) when the activity is first opened.

So I do this in onCreate:

```
final Animation slideRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right);
        slideRight.setDuration(200);

        final Animation slideLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left);
        slideLeft.setDuration(200);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.startAnimation(slideRight);
        recyclerView.startAnimation(slideLeft);
```

but seems like only the right slide works

here are my anims:

left slide

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

right slide

```
<translate
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: how is this related to proposed duplicate?

Comment: why are you starting both animations at once?

Comment: because Idk how to start consecutively? That's the question

Comment: i have updated the answer.. try it and let me know.. @EgeKuzubasioglu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding views in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574805/hiding-views-in-recyclerview)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745980/horizontal-recyclerview-with-nice-animation-android

Comment: @EgeKuzubasioglu check the answer i posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
Animation slideRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right);
Animation slideLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left);
slideRight.setDuration(200);
slideLeft.setDuration(200);
slideRight .setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
               recyclerView.startAnimation(slideLeft);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
  recyclerView.startAnimation(slideRight);
```

Comment: 200 millis is too short setting it 1000 and works like a charm

Comment: yes you can change the numbers ofcourse , i used the numbers you used in the question :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

In this case `slideLeft` animation will work.. because before the `slideRight` is working the `slideleft` is getting started.. so do like this...

```
    slideRight.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            recyclerView.startAnimation(slideLeft);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}
```

**At the end of animation right start the animation left**

**Edit**
*Or you can start only one anim by adding `repeatMode = reverse` and repeatCount = 1` in your anim..*

`android:repeatMode="reverse"    android:repeatCount="1"`

Comment: animations are not starting now

Comment: first start the right animation.. you have to add `view.startAnimation(slideRight)` did u add that ??

Comment: ok you can add the two animation together then by using `repearMode = reverse` and `repeatCount = 1` and start a singlr anim..