# Swipe one item at a time Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I tried adding on Scroll listener for recycler view and made some logic but i am not able to swipe one item at a time. I did some search on internet but i got some third party library which has custom recycler view. Can we implement one item swipe at a time in recycler view? If yes Please tell how?
One item swipe at a time like this [image](https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager/raw/master/horizontal.gif).

Comment: Viewpager is what you're looking for. As for custom transitions go through [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Comment: Thank you. But i cant use ViewPager for scrolling one item in  Recyclerview.

Comment: Um, I meant use Viewpager instead of a RecyclerView.

Comment: Is there any other way without using Viewpager?

Comment: Duplicate question.
Please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41988804/7182978).

Comment: hello @AkshayBhat'AB' can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952965/recyclerview-horizontal-scrolling-to-left?noredirect=1#comment87836903_49952965

Answer (score 42):

This softens the movement between items:

```
public class SnapHelperOneByOne extends LinearSnapHelper {

    @Override
    public int findTargetSnapPosition(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager, int velocityX, int velocityY) {

        if (!(layoutManager instanceof RecyclerView.SmoothScroller.ScrollVectorProvider)) {
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
        }

        final View currentView = findSnapView(layoutManager);

        if (currentView == null) {
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
        }

        LinearLayoutManager myLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager;

        int position1 = myLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        int position2 = myLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

        int currentPosition = layoutManager.getPosition(currentView);

        if (velocityX > 400) {
            currentPosition = position2;
        } else if (velocityX < 400) {
            currentPosition = position1;
        }

        if (currentPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
        }

        return currentPosition;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
LinearSnapHelper linearSnapHelper = new SnapHelperOneByOne();
linearSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Comment: You Are Genius Bro , Thanks

Comment: Why are there constants? 400

Comment: nice but in case of vertical scroll velocityX  replace with velocityY  working for me. and mr user924  400 is used for check then velocity of scroll is below of more for check up scroll or down scroll

Comment: Its really worth. You saved my day bro. Thanks

Comment: If you're using the reverse layout in recyclerView then change the position2 with position1 in the if-else clause. now you'll get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect

Comment: is there a way i can make switch to another item more quicker as in current form it feels very slow

Answer (score 34):

This is late, **i know**.

There is a very **simple** way to get exactly the requested scrolling behaviour with the use of a custom SnapHelper.

Create your own SnapHelper by overwriting the standard one (android.support.v7.widget.LinearSnapHelper).

```
public class SnapHelperOneByOne extends LinearSnapHelper{

    @Override
    public int findTargetSnapPosition(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager, int velocityX, int velocityY){

        if (!(layoutManager instanceof RecyclerView.SmoothScroller.ScrollVectorProvider)) {
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
        }

        final View currentView = findSnapView(layoutManager);

        if( currentView == null ){
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
        }

        final int currentPosition = layoutManager.getPosition(currentView);

        if (currentPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
        }

        return currentPosition;
    }
}
```

This is basicly the stadard method, but without adding a jump counter which gets calculated by scroll speed.

If you swipe fast and long, the next(or previous) view will be centered (shown).

If you swipe slow and short, the current centered view stays centered after release.

I hope this answer can still help anybody.

Comment: Thank you! your answer saved my day

Comment: Is there is any method to increase speed of Swipe. It swipes but it will need full swipe to scroll to next item.

Comment: had you find any way to increase speed of swipe?

Comment: @DheerajRijhwani did you find a solution?

Comment: it's not very good, because you still need to scroll to the end

Comment: not smooth to scroll

Comment: Use the new `PagerSnapHelper()` rather than `LinearShapHelper()`

Comment: loved your Answer buddy Thanks Saved my day bruh

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-HorizontalPaging/

This has the link to something similar to what you have shown in the images. Let me know if there is something additional you are looking for, and I will link the relevant libraries.

Basically the difference between ViewPager and recyclerView is that, in recyclerView you are switching between many item, while in ViewPager you are switching between many fragments or independent pages itself.

I see you are using this https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager, is there any particular use case you have in mind?