# android: one item swipe at a time in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am implementing endless `recyclerView` and using [this](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/daimajia/swipedemo/adapter/RecyclerViewAdapter.java) library for swipe. I am facing the problem in which more than one item is swipe in `recyclerview` at a time. If I drag second view of `recyclerview` and if first view is open then it should be hide means only one item in `recyclerview` show the same time. Below is my adapter

```
    public class Adapter<T> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;
    private List<MyModel> mDataset;

    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 2;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

    private Context context;

    public Adapter(List<MyModel> myDataSet, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mDataset = myDataSet;

        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                    totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                        // End has been reached
                        // Do something
                        if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                            onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                        }
                        loading = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mDataset.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

            vh = new TextViewHolder(itemView);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.progressbar_item, parent, false);
            vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof TextViewHolder) {
            MyModel model = mDataset.get(position);

            ((TextViewHolder) holder).tvFname.setText(model.getStrFname());
            ((TextViewHolder) holder).tvLname.setText(model.getStrLname());

//            SwipeItemRecyclerMangerImpl mItemManger = new SwipeItemRecyclerMangerImpl(Adapter.this);
//            mItemManger.bindView(holder.itemView, position);
        }

        else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        loading = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }

    public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
        void onLoadMore();
    }

    public static class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvFname, tvLname;

        public TextViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            tvFname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvLname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailId);
        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `MainActivity`.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    public SearchView search;
    private ArrayList<MyModel> arrayList  = new ArrayList<MyModel>();
    private Adapter mAdapter;
    protected Handler handler;
    private MyModel model;
    int test=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setRecycler();
    }

    private void setRecycler() {

        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        createlist();  // in this method, Create a list of items.
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //add devider to recycleview.
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext()));

        mAdapter = new Adapter(arrayList, mRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        handler = new Handler();

        mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new Adapter.OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                //add progress item
                arrayList.add(null);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(arrayList.size() - 1);

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //remove progress item
                        arrayList.remove(arrayList.size() - 1);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(arrayList.size());
                        //add items one by one
//                            arrayList.add("Item " + (arrayList.size() + 1));
                        createlist();

                        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(arrayList.size());
                        mAdapter.setLoaded();
                        //or you can add all at once but do not forget to call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, 2000);
                System.out.println("load");
            }
        });
    }

    // this method is used to create list of items.
    public void createlist() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            model = new MyModel();
            model.setStrFname("Testing"+test);
            model.setStrLname("Testing"+i+"@gmail.com");
            arrayList.add(model);
            test++;
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swipe one item at a time Recyclerview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324926/swipe-one-item-at-a-time-recyclerview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem using [this](https://github.com/nikhilpanju/RecyclerViewEnhanced) library and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8nJi3D_SXMzTzFVMm52WjR0UVk/view?usp=sharing
)  is my complete code for load more or endless recyclerview with swipe layout which may help to someone in future.