# Recyclerview withy LinearSnapHelper - snap to next item when release finger from the screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have followed [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324926/swipe-one-item-at-a-time-recyclerview/42197223) to create a recyclerview with viewpager behavior.

Works fine but I need to trigger the scroll to next item when user lift the finger of the screen. Right now only snap to next item when it's 50% visible.

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**

The Crysxd response was the key. To detect the snap direction I added this code at the top of the findTargetSnapPosition function:

```
if (velocityY < 0)
        snapToPrevious = true
else
        snapToNext = true
```

Comment: make your own custom `LinearSnapHelper` class, see: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/recyclerview/src/main/java/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSnapHelper.java#43

Comment: There aren't a simplest solution? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way around a custom SnapHelper. Here is a class you can copy to your project.

## The solution

```
class ControllableSnapHelper(val onSnapped: ((Int) -> Unit)? = null) : LinearSnapHelper() {
    var snappedPosition = 0
    private var snapToNext = false
    private var snapToPrevious = false
    var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null

    override fun attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView?) {
        super.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView
    }

    override fun findTargetSnapPosition(layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager, velocityX: Int, velocityY: Int): Int {
        if (snapToNext) {
            snapToNext = false
            snappedPosition = Math.min(recyclerView?.adapter?.itemCount ?: 0, snappedPosition + 1)
        } else if (snapToPrevious) {
            snapToPrevious = false
            snappedPosition = Math.max(0, snappedPosition - 1)
        } else {
            snappedPosition = super.findTargetSnapPosition(layoutManager, velocityX, velocityY)
        }

        onSnapped?.invoke(snappedPosition)
        return snappedPosition
    }

    fun snapToNext() {
        snapToNext = true
        onFling(Int.MAX_VALUE, Int.MAX_VALUE)
    }

    fun snapToPrevious() {
        snapToPrevious = true
        onFling(Int.MAX_VALUE, Int.MAX_VALUE)
    }
}
```

You can replace `LinearSnapHelper` with `PagerSnapHelper` as well. Simply call `snapToNext()` or `snapToPrevious()`. I also implemented a callback which is passed in the constructor.

## How it works

We simply overwrite the `findTargetSnapPosition(...)` method. This method can return any position and the `SnapHelper` implementation will then compute the scroll animation to get there. The functions `snapToNext()` and `snapToPrevious()` simply set a boolean which tells us to snap to the next or previous view the next time `findTargetSnapPosition(...)` is called. It would also be very simple to add a `snapTo(index: Int)` function. After setting the boolean, we need to start the snap progress. To do so, we call `onFling(...)` which would be called when the user moved the `RecyclerView`. We need to pass in a value which exceeds the minimum velocity set by `SnapHelper`, so we just use `Int.MAX_VALUE`. As we never call `super.findTargetSnapPosition(...)`, the actual velocity used by `PagerSnapHelper` doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll check asap and let you know!!

Comment: Please let me know if you have issues, I can then update my repsonse

Comment: Hi Crysxd!! Works very well. Only I added this peace of code to detect the snap direction: if (velocityY < 0)
            snapToPrevious = true
        else
            snapToNext = true
Thanks a lot for your help!!